# Log marker position only once after it's finished dragging

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Whenever I am dragging my marker, the getPosition is being console logged every 0.1s while the element is being dragged. How can I make it only console log when it's being stopped dragged? I want the same effect as .getRadius() works, it only console logs it when the radius is being changed once.

[image: Unwanted effect, I want to log it only once after position change]

```js
  marker.Circle.addListener('center_changed', function() {
          console.log(marker.getPosition())
        })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the `center_changed` event, use the `dragend` one.

```
marker.Circle.addListener('dragend', function() {
   console.log(marker.getPosition())
});
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/polygon#Circle.dragend

Also it's actually a Circle, not a Marker, that's being dragged.  Only Circle and Map objects have the `center_changed` event.  So it looks like it's a circle attached to your marker.